# Why does the time of rotation only rely on the angle and the length of the string?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, speed, centripetal-force

[image]

My question is in the title. How does the time of rotation in this example have nothing to do with speed? Intuitively, if the bob is going at a faster constant speed the time of rotation would be much smaller. In other words, we would find the same time of rotation no matter what the speed is (we never use the quantity $v$ in any calculation).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: As some friendly advice, usually it's better to quote the relevant part of a text, rather than post a picture. However, overall I like this question, since I think it is about a tricky concept you ran into while studying, rather than "homework help" with a specific problem.

Comment: @Andrew Much appreciated. I thought about this but I was nervous I would negligently leave out that would guide an answer to my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

Physically, the answer does indeed depend on the speed. But, the speed cannot be freely varied independent of other parameters in the problem. The problem has specified the following things:

- the length of the string $L$,
- the angle $\beta$,
- the only forces acting are the string tension and gravity,
- the bob is undergoing circular motion.

This is enough information to completely fix the speed. So, with the parameters you are given, there is no freedom to make the pendulum go faster or slower.

---

**More detailed answer**

In more detail, the key idea is that for circular motion
\begin{equation}
a_r = \frac{v^2}{R}
\end{equation}
where $a_r$ is the radial component of the acceleration. Rearranging this,
\begin{equation}
v = \sqrt{a_r R}
\end{equation}
Because of this equation, the speed is not independent of $a_r$ and $R$.

Meanwhile, as the solution states, $a_r$ and $R$ are fixed in terms of $L$, $\beta$, and $g$ by
\begin{eqnarray}
R &=& L \sin \beta \\
a_R &=& g \tan \beta
\end{eqnarray}
Therefore
\begin{equation}
v = \sqrt{g L \sin\beta \tan\beta}
\end{equation}
Since $L$ and $\beta$ are given, you aren't free to vary $v$.

---

**Digging a bit deeper**

However, we can see how your intuition works, by thinking about what kind of change to the parameters of the problem we could make to increase $v$, and see if that makes the time go up or down. We will assume the length of the string is fixed, so the only parameter we can change is the angle $\beta$.

Here's a plot of $\sin\beta \tan\beta$ from $\beta$ in the range $[0, \pi/2)$

[image]

We can see that as we increase $\beta$, this function increases. This means that as we increase $\beta$, the velocity increases. We also note from the fact that $T \propto \sqrt \cos \beta$, that as $\beta$ increases, $T$ decreases. This matches your intuition, that as the speed increases, the time decreases.

Somewhat counterintuitively, increasing $\beta$ will also increase the radius, since $R = L \sin \beta$. You might think that this would tend to increase the time, since now there is a larger circle to traverse. However, to maintain circular motion with a larger radius, we also need a larger radial acceleration, and so a larger velocity. So everything works out in the end, but you can see that the constraint of circular motion can cause the different parameters in the problem to be related to each other in surprising ways.

As a final remark, we have more freedom if we violate the assumption that the only forces acting are the string and gravity. If we built a circular track and had the particle follow this, the particle could travel at any speed. The forces needed for the centripetal acceleration would come from the *constraint forces* fixing the particle to the track.

Comment: Andrew! I seriously do not know how to thank you enough! I'd +1 $\times 3$ if I could!

Comment: I realise this question and answer has not garnered much recognition so I dont know if you'd care to edit your answer, but I did notice that $$R=L\sin \beta$$ not $$R=L\cos \beta$$ which gives $$v=\sqrt{Lg\sin \beta \tan \beta}$$ But to emphasize... this still is an expression in terms of the fixed $\beta$ and $L$ so the crux of your argument does not change.

Comment: @ChrisChristopherson Ah, thanks for pointing that out! I'll see if I can fix that.

Comment: @ChrisChristopherson I edited the answer to fix this!